# Sql Server - The partner transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im using SQL Trigger in SQL SERVER , and when i added an execution of Stored Procedure, the ff error is kept showing.

> Error: OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "NSLINK" returned message "The partner transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions.".

```
 USE [SysConfig]
    GO
    /****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[TestingTrigger]    Script Date: 27/08/2020 5:05:13 PM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TestingTrigger]
        ON [dbo].[TestingMaster]
        AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
    AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
        Declare @vActivity varchar(50)
                ,@vProgramCode varchar(100)
    
    If exists (Select * from inserted) and not exists(Select * from deleted)
    begin
        SET @vActivity = 'INSERT';
        SELECT @vProgramCode = ProgramCode from inserted i;
        INSERT into TestingMaster1(SqncNo,[Action]) 
        VALUES(@vProgramCode,@vActivity)
    
        exec EmployeeDB.dbo.[spn_SendProgram] 'ProgramCode','',@vProgramCode,'','','Test',@vActivity,'POST'
    end
    
    if exists(SELECT * from inserted) and exists (SELECT * from deleted)
    begin
        SET @vActivity = 'UPDATE';
        SELECT @vProgramCode = ProgramCode from inserted i;
        INSERT into TestingMaster1(SqncNo,[Action]) 
        VALUES(@vProgramCode,@vActivity)
        exec EmployeeDB.dbo.[spn_SendProgram] 'ProgramCode','',@vProgramCode,'','','Test',@vActivity,'PUT'
    end
    
    END
```

Comment: I'm assuming `spn_SendProgram` makes use of a linked server `NSLINK`. The problem you are seeing is your transaction is elevated to a distributed transaction, this means you require a DTC (Distributed Transaction Coordinator) and the linked server should be configured to allow remote transactions. If running code in a trigger, this is automatically enlisted in the transaction invoking the insert/update trigger. All statements run in a transaction even if you didn't specify one.

Comment: You suffer from a very common problem - triggers fire per statement, not per row. Your code assumes a single row is affected by the insert/update/merge statement.